# How to load only specific modules routes and configuration in pingpong laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have dozens of modules in laravel. Is there any way to not load some specific module routes and configuration? I am using pingpong module package in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan module:disable blog
```